# Unity Always Moving Right

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I need help with making a script that makes my sprite automatically move right from whenever they start playing, like "Geometry Dash". I've tried making a script for it, but it is really jittery. Whenever the character would jump, he would float over the ground for a few seconds before landing. Here is the script:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Time.deltaTime instead of a fixed float

```
function Update () {
transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```